# Why is there extra space at the top and bottom of my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Starting in iOS 9.3.2, there is extra space at the top and bottom.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

There is about 20 pixels of unexplained padding. Can anyone explain where do they come from?

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

This doesn't work for me.

Comment: please share your storyboard

Comment: Hey, implement your ViewDidLayoutSubviews method

Comment: show storyboard with constarints

Comment: Thank you,i have solved it.Other people creat this controller with XIB,i set the style as Plain.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `contentInset` property for `UITableView`

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0);
```

This will remove the extra spaces from top and bottom

Comment: Thank you,i have solved it.Other people creat this controller with XIB,i set the style as Plain.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if your table view in touching the edges of viewcontroller.

2.If not then make it touch each side of th view controller by expanding your tableview

3.Select your table view from Document outline and go to Pin menu of autolayout

4.Add 4 pin constraints and set the value to 0 as you can see in image below

5.Uncheck "Constraints to margins" and click add 4 constraints

[image]

Hope it will help.!

Comment: Thank you,i have solved it.Other people creat this controller with XIB,i set the style as Plain.